# Hadoop, When I Run the start-all.sh File Only the JPS Daemon Starts

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to set up Hadoop for the first time on my M1 mac running Big Sur. I updated all the xml files, made the ssh key, and was able to run "namenode -format" without an issue. However, when I run "start-all.sh" then "jps" only the jps daemon shows as running.

Start-all.sh contents:

```
JAVA_HOME="/opt/homebrew/opt/java/openjdk/libexec/Contents/Home" exec "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/hadoop/3.3.1/libexec/sbin/start-all.sh"  "$@"
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: 1) Not sure M1 chips are supported by Hadoop, although, I guess that's up to Java, but Java 8/11 likely dont 2) Try using `hadoop namenode` and `hadoop datanode` command separately to start the daemons and watch their logs

Comment: I tried that and received an error "WARNING: log4j.properties is not found. HADOOP_CONF_DIR may be incomplete.
ERROR: Invalid HADOOP_YARN_HOME" which I fixed, however  same result. There are reddit users who claim to use hadoop daily on m1 without problems so I'll try there as well. Thank you.

Comment: The log4j file should be setup correctly, assuming all those other env-vars work... Which should give you more logs than just that